# preprocessing image data with keras

Tags: tf.keras

i want to split images from my dataset

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    
    image_size=(img_size, img_size),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="training",
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)
vali_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    data,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    
    image_size=(img_size, img_size),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset="validation",
    interpolation="bilinear",
    follow_links=False,
)

test_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    test,
    labels="inferred",
    label_mode="int",
    class_names=None,
    color_mode="rgb",
    
    image_size=(img_size, img_size),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=123,

    interpolation="bilinear",

)
```

i get this error

```
No images found in directory /content/teste. Allowed formats: ('.bmp', '.gif', '.jpeg', '.jpg', '.png')

Found 0 files belonging to 0 classes.
Using 0 files for training.
```

"train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory" is underlined in red and there are many pictures in my directory

i try with :`train_ds = tf.keras.experimental.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory` but i obtain the same result